# Printing char even parity

Tags: c

This may be a stupid question but I can't seem to figure this out.

I've written a program the takes a char as input, outputs the char and its hexadecimal value then checks for even parity and sets the parity bit to 1 and again outputs the "new" char and it's hex value. However using printf and %c doesn't seem to be the way to go and I don't understand why or how to fix it, so I would very much appreciate if someone could explain why not and what I should be doing instead. Oh and feel free to comment on the code I am learning after all so criticism is always good :)

```
int checkParity(unsigned char myChar); //returns 0 if even 1 if odd

int main()  {
  int i;
  unsigned char input;

  printf("Enter char: ");
  scanf("%c", &input);

  /* print unchanged char and hex with */
  printf("c7: %c ", input);
  printf("hex: %x \n", input);

  /*if parity is odd*/
  if(checkParity(input)){
    /*change to even*/
    input = (input|0x80);
  }

  /* print char and hex even parity */
  printf("c8: %c ", input);
  printf("hex: %x \n", input);  

  return 0;
}

int checkParity(unsigned char myChar){
  int i;
  int parity = 0;

  while(myChar){    //while myChar != 0
    parity += (myChar&1);   //add result of myChar AND 1 to parity
    myChar = myChar>>1;     //shift bits left by 1
  }
  //printf("parity equals: %d\n", parity);
  if(parity%2){ // if odd parity
    return 1;
  }
  else { //even parity
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the output, and what do you expect it to be?

Comment: After adding the parity bit I simply want to print the character that was put in so for example 'L' followed by the new hex value. right now it prints a weird looking square instead of L.

Comment: Beside the fact that >> is shift bit right and not left , try to focus your question to part of the code that is not working. In example , I dont know if you check the checkparity function behaviour

Comment: That's because it's no longer an `L'  :-)  The parity bit happens to be the most significant bit, and it's treated as data.  So you're actually adding 128 to the hex code of the character.  Search for "Extended ASCII table" to find out what the new character is.  If you want to print the original character, you can copy it into another variable and print that.

Comment: oops thanks didn't notice I'd written left! well I've checked that the checkParity function works a few times and it seems to. Like I mentioned the part that isn't working is printing an char with the parity bit set to 1 using %c. Our lecturer mentioned it would not work but I can't figure out why.

Comment: Once you add the 0x80 parity bit to odd parity characters, it may not be a printable character or at best funky extended ASCII graphics and such.

Comment: @Adam Liss Thanks that makes sense I may have been misunderstanding what my assignment is asking of me and took it as an instruction to force the L to show up somehow :)

Comment: @kenny that would explain the "funky" box that is showing up :)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your parity-calculating code and it isn't what you were asking about, but just for fun you might like to contemplate the following: `int checkParity(unsigned char c) { c ^= c>>4; c ^= c>>2; c ^= c>>1; return c&1; }`. Less aggressively, note that since `parity%2` is always either 0 or 1, the last bit of your function is exactly equivalent to `return parity%2;`.

Comment: One minor issue you have is that you don't ensure that the parity bit is ignored when calculating the correct parity.  So, if the user only types 7-bit ASCII codes, you'll be OK, but if the user types accented characters in ISO-8859-1 or something similar, you will count the parity bit that is already there, confusing yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What are parity bits?**

Parity bits are a simple form of error-checking that can be used, for example, when you transmit data from one machine to another.  If both machines agree on, say, even parity, then the receiver will know that any incoming characters that *don't* have even parity were received in error.  However, parity of any type can only identify an *odd* number of erroneous bits: two errors in a single character will cancel each other, and the resulting parity will be correct.  Moreover, the receiver cannot determine *which* bit (or bits) are incorrect; parity provides error *detection*, but not error *correction*.

**How should received data be processed?**

The receiver should calculate and validate the parity of each incoming character.  If it detects a character with invalid parity, it should indicate the error somehow.  In the best case, it may be able to ask the transmitter to re-transmit the character.

Once the character is validated, the receiver must *strip the parity bit* before passing the character on for further processing.  This is because, since the parity bit is used for error detection, it is "lost" from the data payload.  Thus, enabling parity will reduce the number of available data values by half.  For example, 8 bits can have one of 256 possible values (0 - 255).  If one bit is used for parity, only 7 bits remain to encode the data, leaving only 128 valid values.

---

Since you asked for comments/criticism, here's a revised, commented version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Consider using a boolean data type, as the function returns
// "true" or "false" rather than an arbitrary integer.
int isOddParity(unsigned char myChar);


int main(void) {
  unsigned char input;

  printf("Enter char: ");
  scanf("%c", &input);

  // Force even parity by setting MSB if the parity is odd.
  unsigned char even = isOddParity(input) ? input | 0x80 : input;

  // Print the original char, original hex, and even-parity hex
  // Print hex values as 0xHH, zero-padding if necessary.  This program
  // will probably never print hex values less than 0x10, but zero-padding
  // is good practice.
  printf("orig char: %c\n", input);
  printf("orig  hex: 0x%02x\n", input);
  printf("even  hex: 0x%02x\n", even);
  return 0;
}

// Calculate the parity of myChar.
// Returns 1 if odd, 0 if even.
int isOddParity(unsigned char myChar) {
  int parity = 0;

  // Clear the parity bit from myChar, then calculate the parity of
  // the remaining bits, starting with the rightmost, by toggling
  // the parity for each '1' bit.
  for (myChar &= ~0x80;  myChar != 0;  myChar >>= 1) {
    parity ^= (myChar & 1);   // Toggle parity on each '1' bit.
  }
  return parity;
}
```